# Javascript to auto add SLASHES in input box (Date, Time Structure)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is it possible to add SLASHES in input box automatically ?

i need in this way `1234/12345/12345`

and for Date and time.. like this `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

is it possible to do both in java script ?

```
Roll Number : <input id="number" name="number" value="____/_____/_____" >
Date and Time : <input id="time" name="time" value="__/__/____ __:__:__">
```

tried that... but didn't worked

Comment: Yes, you can use Regular Expressions (aka regex or regexp). Use that term to find solutions, you'll find many.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.inputmask.

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask